# Precompiling controller assets in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, rake-task

I have a separate scss file for each controller and I don't import them all to the application.css file so that I can include controller specific stylesheet and js file in the layout.

So in the layout I do:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller], :media => "all" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag params[:controller] %>
```

But when I run rake assets:precompile I don't get compiled assets for the controllers.

I looked for solutions on the web, but they all stated to add needed files to the config.assets.precompile staitment. And I don't know what to put there so that all the assets in subfolders of app/assets/stylesheets and subfolders of app/assets/javascripts get compiled automaticaly.

**UPDATE 1**

OK, I will compile all them in one file, but there are two problems:

1. I have a _base.scss file containing all the needed variables and imports, and have renames application.css to application.css.scss so that i can import that file before everything else:

   ```
   @import 'base';
   @import 'style';
   @import 'forms';
   ```

How do I need to do that with a manifest? Could not find a way to import the whole directory with scss itself.

1. I have some different actions for same selectors in different controllers. What is the easyest way to separate those actions and define witch should be processed on a particular page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bad idea because it adds extra HTTP requests for each page load, requires a lot of extra files (most of which will be empty, there's rarely going to be actual controller-specific CSS/JS), and ignores browser caching (cache the application.css/js once and forget about it).

Better to write your CSS/JS in such a way that you can include it all together and use the asset pipeline properly.

Comment: Updated the question with the problems on this one.

Comment: I prefer to have application CSS & JS and then per controller CSS and JS.  Since the controllers are splitting up my application into specific portions.  I don't like dumping all my JS & CSS into 1 file.  It can be done, but why have all the unused selectors and empty jquery selectors.

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

to the file config/application.rb

add this line:

```
config.assets.precompile += ["controller1.js", "controller1.css", "controller2.js", "controller3.js"]
```

and next time when you run assets:precompile it will compile this files also

Comment: I am looking for a way to do this automatically, but can't find a clean one.

Answer (score 0):

what about something like:

```
config.assets.precompile += Dir::entries("app/assets/javascripts").
                               map{|f| f[/^(?!application\.).*\.js/]}.compact
```